# how to return redirect to route with slug

Tags: php, redirect, routes, laravel-5

i want to redirect to my thread show but something error and missing
here is my route

```
Route::get('forum/{forumthread}', [
    'uses'  =>  'ForumController@show',
    'as'    =>  'forum.show'
    ]);

Route::get('forum/{forumthread}/create', [
    'uses'  =>  'ForumController@indexcreate',
    'as'    =>  'forum.index.create'
    ]);
```

here is my controller

```
public function indexcreate($slug){

    $forum = forumthread::where('slug', $slug)->first();

    return view('forum.index.indexcreate', compact('forum'));

}



public function indexstore(Request $request, $slug){

    $forumindex = new forumindex;
    $forumindex->title = $request->title;
    $forumindex->body = $request->body;
    $forumindex->slug = EasySlug::generateSlug($forumindex->title, $separator = '-');
    $forumindex->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $forumindex->save();

    return redirect()->route('forum.show', $forum->slug);

}
```

help me for this thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to wrap the second argument of the *route()* function in array?

```
return redirect()->route('forum.show', ['slug' => $forum->slug]);
```

Here's the what the [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirects) says:

> If your route has parameters, you may pass them as the second argument
>   to the route method:
>
> // For a route with the following URI: profile/{id}
>
> return redirect()->route('profile', ['id' => 1]);

Comment: still getting error
Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\ForumController::indexstore()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return redirect()->action('ForumController@show', array('slug'=>$forum->slug));
```